# How to use "no" in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a number of job posts in our index and we need to find 10 posts with **"no experience"** in the name or description. For this we form a request:

```
{
   "from":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "simple_query_string":{
                  "default_operator":"and",
                  "fields":[
                     "name",
                     "description"
                  ],
                  "query":"no experience"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":10
}
```

However, the results of this request contain job posts with "at least 1 year of experience needed", "must have previous experience", and so on. I assume this happens because of the standard analyzer and there is a lot of articles about how to add **stopwords** (i.e. words we want to exclude from search), but how to **include** "no" is a great mistery for me.

Comment: Can you please share your index mapping and some sample data over which you are performing this search query ?

Comment: please share the mappings of name and description fields. By default ES uses standard analyzer which simply stores "no experience" as ["no","experience"]. If your field value is "no experience" and you want an exact match , please apply mapping type "keyword" on your two fields  , so that ES stores the word as is w/o splitting